# Customize the ui from Keycloak Permission

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, keycloak

I'm new to Keycloak and I'm using it to protect a Spring Boot Vaadin Application.

I want, after user login, to customize the UI basing it by permissions that user have.

I'm enabled to get the role associated of my user:

```
    KeycloakPrincipal principal =  (KeycloakPrincipal) VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getUserPrincipal();
    Set<String> roles = principal.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken().getResourceAccess("myresource").getRoles();
```

Is possible to get also the list of policies/permission associated at this role?

Thanks in advance.